java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found - issue on android older version (4,5)
API getting errors like CertPathValidatorException. This will happen only the android older version like 4.4.4(Kitkat).  The same API is working in a higher version.

Most likely the server uses a Let's encrypt certificate which isn't trusted anymore on Android before 7.1. On Android prior to Android 6 you can manually install the Let's Encrypt root CA certificate as user certificate.

Hi! Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78309587/4110900
